# Use composer's autoload to load OpenTBS plugin for tinybutstrong

Tags: php, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am using [tinybutstrong](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/) and it's [opentbs plugin](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php). Until now I did use an explicit require of the two source files for that but I want to switch to composer with autoloading.  So I want to go from this

```php
<?php
include 'tbs_class.php';
include 'tbs_plugin_opentbs.php';
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL,  OPENTBS_PLUGIN);
```

to this (or something similar)

```php
<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL,  OPENTBS_PLUGIN);
```

but that fails with the error `TinyButStrong Error with plug-in 'OPENTBS_PLUGIN': no class named 'OPENTBS_PLUGIN' is found, and no function named 'tbspi_OPENTBS_PLUGIN_OnInstall' is found.`  So it seems composer can not load the relevant file just based on the constant's name.

How can I get composer's autoload to pick up the plugin file?

Comment: Before calling `$TBS->Plugin()` you can add `$ok = class_exists('clsOpenTBS', true);` This should invoke your custom autoloader. OpenTBS is currently version 1.10.0, but the next version will provide a clean solution for this problem.

Comment: Yea I came up with a similar "hack": I just looked at the plugin code and am now creating a throw away instance of a class from the plugin code to force the loading of the script. I just put `new clsOpenTBS;` before the `$TBS->Plugin()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
//load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

 //// Initialize the TBS instance
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong; // new instance of TBS
$ok = class_exists('clsOpenTBS', true);
$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL,  OPENTBS_PLUGIN);// load the OpenTBS plugin
```

Comment: Add a bit of explanation to the code, i.e. how does this resolves the question?

Comment: $ok = class_exists('clsOpenTBS', true);    this invokes the autoloader

Comment: This was actually first suggested by @Skrol29 in a comment on the question.